# How can I export data from Bigquery to an external server in a CSV?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow

I need to automate a process to extract data from Google Big Query and exported to an external CSV in a external server outside of the GCP.

I just researching how to to that I found some commands to run from my External Server. But I prefer to do everything in GCP to avoid possible problems.

**To run the query to CSV in Google storage**

```
bq --location=US extract --compression GZIP 'dataset.table' gs://example-bucket/myfile.csv
```

**To Download the csv from Google Storage**

```
gsutil cp gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[OBJECT_NAME] [OBJECT_DESTINATION]
```

But I would like to  hear your suggestions

Comment: Your approach looks good. What would you like to improve?

Comment: Thanks @FelipeHoffa ,  The only problem is that I want to run everything from GCP  and magically have a daily exported CSV in  a local server from the client.

Comment: and you have that already working! what could be better than what you have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to fully automatize this process, I would do the following:

1. **Create a [Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/) to handle the export**:

This is the more lightweight solution, as Cloud Functions are serverless, and  provide flexibility to implement code with the [Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries). See the [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart-console), I recommend you to use the console to create the functions to start with.

In this example I recommend you to trigger the Cloud Function [from an HTTP request](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/http), i.e. when the function URL is called, it will run the code inside of it.

An example Cloud Function code in Python, that creates the export when a HTTP request is made:

**main.py**

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

def hello_world(request):
    project_name = "MY_PROJECT"
    bucket_name = "MY_BUCKET"
    dataset_name = "MY_DATASET"
    table_name = "MY_TABLE"
    destination_uri = "gs://{}/{}".format(bucket_name, "bq_export.csv.gz")

    bq_client = bigquery.Client(project=project_name)

    dataset = bq_client.dataset(dataset_name, project=project_name)
    table_to_export = dataset.table(table_name)

    job_config = bigquery.job.ExtractJobConfig()
    job_config.compression = bigquery.Compression.GZIP

    extract_job = bq_client.extract_table(
        table_to_export,
        destination_uri,
        # Location must match that of the source table.
        location="US",
        job_config=job_config,
    )  
    return "Job with ID {} started exporting data from {}.{} to {}".format(extract_job.job_id, dataset_name, table_name, destination_uri)
```

**requirements.txt**

```
google-cloud-bigquery
```

Note that the job will run asynchronously in the background, you will receive a return response with the job ID, which you can use to check the state of the export job in the Cloud Shell, by running:

```
bq show -j <job_id>
```

2. **Create a [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/) scheduled job**:

Follow this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/creating) to get started. You can set the Frequency with the [standard cron format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), for example `0 0 * * *` will run the job   every day at midnight.

As a target, choose `HTTP`, in the URL put the Cloud Function HTTP URL (you can find it in the console, inside the Cloud Function details, under the Trigger tab), and as `HTTP method` choose `GET`.

Create it, and you can test it in the Cloud Scheduler by pressing the `Run now` button in the Console.

3. **Synchronize your external server and the bucket**:

Up until now you only have scheduled exports to run every 24 hours, now to synchronize the bucket contents with your local computer, you can use the [`gsutil rsync`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync) command. If you want to save the imports, lets say to the `my_exports` folder, you can run, in your external server:

```
gsutil rsync gs://BUCKET_WITH_EXPORTS /local-path-to/my_exports
```

To periodically run this command in your server, you could create a standard [cron job in your crontab](https://linuxize.com/post/scheduling-cron-jobs-with-crontab/) inside your external server, to run each day as well, just at a few hours later than the bigquery export, to ensure that the export has been made.

**Extra**:

I have hard-coded most of the variables in the Cloud Function to be always the same. However, you can send parameters to the function, if you do a `POST` request instead of a `GET` request, and send the parameters as data in the body.

You will have to change the Cloud Scheduler job to send a `POST` request to the Cloud Function HTTP URL, and in the same place you can set the body to send the parameters regarding the `table`, `dataset` and `bucket`, for example. This will allow you to run exports from different tables at different hours, and to different buckets.

Comment: What if you need a custom a query to export data by joining several tables?